# How to insert multiple checkbox data to database using Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Can somebody help me? I have question. I have view, name is **pascasarjana.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Program studi dan konsentrasi yang diminati</label><br/>
      <input name="prodis" type="checkbox" value="p1">Program Studi Magister Manajemen<br/>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <input name="prodis" type="checkbox" value="p2">Program Studi Magister Teknik Sipil
      <select name="konsentrasi" class="form-control" id="konsentrasi1">
        <option value="">Pilih Konsentrasi</option>
        <option value="k1">Manajemen Konstruksi</option>
        <option value="k2">Transportasi</option>
        <option value="k3">Struktur</option>
      </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <input name="prodis" type="checkbox" value="p3">Program Studi Magister Ilmu Hukum
      <select name="konsentrasi" class="form-control" id="konsentrasi2">
        <option value="">Pilih Konsentrasi</option>
        <option value="k4">Hukum Bisnis</option>
        <option value="k5">Hukum Ketatanegaraan</option>
        <option value="k6">Hukum Agraria</option>
        <option value="k7">Litigasi</option>
      </select>
      </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <input name="prodis" type="checkbox" value="p4">Program Studi Magister Teknik Informatika
  <select name="konsentrasi" class="form-control" id="konsentrasi3">
    <option value="">Pilih Konsentrasi</option>
    <option value="k8">Soft Computing</option>
    <option value="k9">Enterprise Information System</option>
    <option value="k10">Mobile Computing</option>
  </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <input name="prodis" type="checkbox" value="p5">Program Studi Magister Teknik Arsitektur
  <select name="konsentrasi" class="form-control" id="konsentrasi4">
    <option value="">Pilih Konsentrasi</option>
    <option value="k11">Arsitektur Digital</option>
  </select>
  </div>
```

AND I confused, how to insert multiple checkbox and select option data to database in my controller and model.

Comment: where is multiple checkbox in your view ?

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your HTML entities as arrays

Eg.

- `input name="prodis"` to `input name="prodis[]"`
- `select name="konsentrasi"` to `select name="konsentrasi[]"`

Then print $_POST in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to get data from select box on the basis of ticked checkbox.

For getting values from checkbox you need to define checkbox name as an array. In my code I am using exact indexes so we can get select box values accordingly.

I guess below first checkbox there should be another select box. Ignoring this select box (Which is actually not here), I am giving custom indexes here. Instead, we also can use like **profis[]** which actually auto generate indexes by incrementing it one on each occurrence in HTML

You can implement validation too. Here are modified code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Program studi dan konsentrasi yang diminati</label><br/>
<input name="prodis[1]" type="checkbox" value="p1">Program Studi Magister Manajemen<br/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input name="prodis[2]" type="checkbox" value="p2">Program Studi Magister Teknik Sipil
<select name="konsentrasi[2]" class="form-control" id="konsentrasi1">
    <option value="">Pilih Konsentrasi</option>
    <option value="k1">Manajemen Konstruksi</option>
    <option value="k2">Transportasi</option>
    <option value="k3">Struktur</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input name="prodis[3]" type="checkbox" value="p3">Program Studi Magister Ilmu Hukum
<select name="konsentrasi[3]" class="form-control" id="konsentrasi2">
    <option value="">Pilih Konsentrasi</option>
    <option value="k4">Hukum Bisnis</option>
    <option value="k5">Hukum Ketatanegaraan</option>
    <option value="k6">Hukum Agraria</option>
    <option value="k7">Litigasi</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input name="prodis[4]" type="checkbox" value="p4">Program Studi Magister Teknik Informatika
<select name="konsentrasi[4]" class="form-control" id="konsentrasi3">
    <option value="">Pilih Konsentrasi</option>
    <option value="k8">Soft Computing</option>
    <option value="k9">Enterprise Information System</option>
    <option value="k10">Mobile Computing</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input name="prodis[5]" type="checkbox" value="p5">Program Studi Magister Teknik Arsitektur
<select name="konsentrasi[5]" class="form-control" id="konsentrasi4">
    <option value="">Pilih Konsentrasi</option>
    <option value="k11">Arsitektur Digital</option>
</select>
```

At controller end you can just check if index 2 **$this->input->post('prodis[2]')** then get the value of select box with index 2 **$this->input->post('konsentrasi[2]'**

You can check it dynamically by keeping code redundancy in your mind. Let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Insert Multiple data using check box or anything on HTML.Just use array "[]".

```
<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="checkbox">
<select name="select[]"></select>
```

Can also array values like [2],[4],[5] anythings

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
  public function insert()
  {
   //Insert second stage details for employer into database.
   $Specilized_category = $this->input->post('spec_cat');
   $data=array(
     'Specilized_category'=>json_encode(implode(",", $Specilized_category)),
   );
  $this->db->insert('tbl_employer', $data);
```